# Re Enabling the click function doesn't works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to disable the click function of the select tag which works perfectly fine but re-enabling doesn't work. here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/103/
My code is as follows:

Html:

```
<select class="select-cities" name="city" id="optlist" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Frederiksberg</option>
    <option>Vanløse</option>
    <option>Glostrup</option>
    <option>Brøndby</option>
    <option>Roskilde</option>
    <option>Køge</option>
    <option>Gentofte</option>
    <option>Hillerød</option>
    <option>Tårnby</option>
    <option>Vallensbæk</option>
</select>

<br/>
<select class="chosen-cities" name="chosen-cities-name" id="optlist1" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.select-cities').click(function () {
   $('.select-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');    
   if($('#optlist1 option').size() == 1) {
      $('.select-cities').off('click');  
   }
});

$('.chosen-cities').click(function () {
   $('.chosen-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.select-cities');   
   $('.select-cities').on('click');    
});
```

Comment: You aren't using `on` correctly here. Check [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You can't turn `off` and `on` a handler like this.

Comment: lol, who is givin `-` to solutions. They are close to solution.

Comment: [Is this what you're trying to achieve](http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/113/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good idea would be to reset your initial state... imagine you had your cities ordered alphabetically `.append()` is not the way to go, so in that case:

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/zukaju/1/edit)

```
function selectCity(){
  $('.select-cities').one("click", function () {
      var opt = $(":selected", this);
      $(".chosen-cities").append( opt.clone() );
      opt.hide();
  });
}

selectCity();


$('.chosen-cities').on("click", "option", function () {
     $(this).remove();
     $('.select-cities :selected').show();
     selectCity();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/CHBXp/5/

when clicking on first select, if there is only one item in the second select, simply do not add another one. The event exists , but it does nothing until you do not have 0 items in the second select

```
$('.select-cities').click(function () {
    if ($('#optlist1 option').size() == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    $('.select-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');
});

$('.chosen-cities').click(function () {
    $('.chosen-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.select-cities');
});
```

EDIT
remove only `$(this)`, the option clicked, and not `(option:selected)` , because on a multiselect , the `:selected` options may be multiple

```
$('.select-cities option').click(function () {
    if ($('#optlist1 option').size() == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    $(this).remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');
});

$('.chosen-cities').click(function () {
    $('.chosen-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.select-cities');
});
```

Comment: best answer.
thanks for pointing out the loophole in my code.
it really helped me a lot.
can you suggest how can i add search functionality for the select cities list...

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/111/

```
function onSelecClick(){
   $('.select-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');    
   if($('#optlist1 option').size() == 1) {
      $('.select-cities').off('click');  
   }
}
$('.select-cities').click(onSelecClick);

$('.chosen-cities').click(function () {
   $('.chosen-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.select-cities');   
   $('.select-cities').on('click',onSelecClick);    
});
```

Btw if you multiselect, you can add more then one item at once.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.
the solution for the multiselect has already been given above.
by using this:
$(this).remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 var handler = function(e){
 $('.select-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');

  if($('#optlist1 option').size() == 1) {
      $('.select-cities').off('click');

     }
  }    

 $('.select-cities').click(handler);

 $('.chosen-cities').click(function () {
    $('.chosen-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.select-cities');

    $('.select-cities').on('click',handler);    
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MzG8K/

Answer (score -2):

It is because you aren't using the live methods for dynamic content in jQuery. Use the `on()` method.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.select-cities', function () {
    $('.select-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');
    if ($('#optlist1 option').size() == 1) {
        $('.select-cities').off('click');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.chosen-cities', function () {
    $('.chosen-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.select-cities');
    $('.select-cities').on('click');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/104/)

Comment: See my comment about `on` on the question. It's not doing what you think.

Comment: but i want only one value to enter the second list.
using 'on' method doesn't go well with the code.

Comment: @Kunal Then just return, or put the logic in an if block, don't try to disable the event handler. See my answer.